# AddIn greyed background window

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

I have a problem regarding an AddIn I published.

To insure that I can easily upgrade the AddIn to all users I implemented a self-updating code which run on startup on two separate AddIn.

**Loader AddIn** run this sub on *Workbook_open*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Workbook_Open
' Open the add-in and close this workbook
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim DateNetwork As Date
Dim DateLocal As Date
Const FilePath As String = "C:\Filepath\Add In"

On Error Resume Next
DateNetwork = FileDateTime(FilePath & "\PT Core.xlam")
DateLocal = FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PT Core.xlam") 'Note: using on error resume next above means DateLocal will be 0 if there is no file, so it will always download the latest.
If DateNetwork > DateLocal Then
    Workbooks("PT Core.xlam").Close savechanges:=False 'Ensure the addin has not loaded already
    FileCopy FilePath & "\PT Core.xlam", ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PT Core.xlam"
End If
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PT Core.xlam"
ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

While **Main AddIn** run this code at *Workbook_open*

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

And the **CExcelEvents** class

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Excel.Application
End Sub
Private Sub App_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.Run "ContextMenu.AddToCellMenu", Target
End Sub
```

All of which allow me to trap right_click event at an application level.

When a file is opened, the loader which is activated as a AddIn launch and then start the Main AddIn. The loader closes, then the file opens. 
However the AddIn create a greyed Excel instance window at startup which give the impression that two files are opened. When I close the file, the AddIn stays loaded and I have to manually close the App.

Is there something I did wrong? I can't seem to figure why this behaviour happen.

I already deleted my PERSONAL.XLSB that I do not use.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to find some explanation about my problem.

I only had installed the loader Add-In which were loading the main Add-In. It had the same behavior as if I were trying to open my xlam file from the file explorer.

I've installed the Main Add-In as well as the Loader Add-In and I changed the code as follow.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Workbook_Open
' Open the add-in and close this workbook
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim DateNetwork As Date
Dim DateLocal As Date
Const FilePath As String = "C:\Filepath\Add In"

On Error Resume Next
DateNetwork = FileDateTime(FilePath & "\PT Core.xlam")
DateLocal = FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PT Core.xlam") 'Note: using on error resume next above means DateLocal will be 0 if there is no file, so it will always download the latest.
If DateNetwork > DateLocal Then
    Workbooks("PT Core.xlam").Close savechanges:=False 'Ensure the addin has not loaded already
    FileCopy FilePath & "\PT Core.xlam", ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PT Core.xlam"
    Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PT Core.xlam"
End If

ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

The problem still occurs when the users versions are updated and the Main Add-In is start from the Loader but once the user closes and open Excel again it's skipped and works correctly.